# Property is user defined?

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I now in a list obtained with Type.GetProperties() if the properties are user-defined?

For example

```
class test
{
     public string propertyOne{get;set;}
     public string propertyTwo{get;set;}
}
```

With `typeof(test).GetProperties()` I get two PropertyInfo, how can I now they are user defined?

Information about the context, here is the test that should pass

```
    [Test]
    public void GetFullNameScalarPropertiesTest()
    {
        // Act
        var properties = ReflectionHelper.GetFullNameScalarProperties(typeof(Parent));

        // Assert
        Assert.True(properties.Contains("PropertyOne"));
        Assert.True(properties.Contains("Child.PropertyTwo"));
        Assert.True(properties.Contains("Child.GrandChild.PropertyThree"));
        Assert.That(properties.Count, Is.EqualTo(3));
    }

    class Parent
    {
        public Parent()
        {
            Child = new Child();
        }

        public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
        public Child Child { get; set; }
    }

    class Child
    {
        public Child()
        {
            GrandChild = new GrandChild();
        }

        public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
        public GrandChild GrandChild { get; set; }
    }

    class GrandChild
    {
        public string PropertyThree { get; set; }
    }
```

So, in a recursive method I'm getting properties and creating a list with the names

ATM the code that pass this test is

```
    public static IList<string> GetFullNameScalarProperties(Type type)
    {
        var lista = new List<string>();
        var path = string.Empty;
        var properties = type.GetProperties();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
            GetFullNameScalarProperties(propertyInfo, path, lista);

        return lista;
    }

    private static void GetFullNameScalarProperties(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, string path, ICollection<string> lista)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            path += ".";

        path += propertyInfo.Name;

        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName != null)
            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName.StartsWith("System"))
            {
                lista.Add(path);
                return;
            }

        var properties = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetProperties();

        foreach (var pi in properties)
            GetFullNameScalarProperties(pi, path, lista);
    }
```

Comment: user defined? do you mean non-inherited or non-overridden?

Comment: I will try to clarify what I need

Comment: Your update still isn't very clear. However, some guesswork: You are looking for a reasonable way to tell whether *a property is of a type that belongs within a set of some specific types* in order to decide in `GetFullNameScalarProperties` whether to drill down into a particular property's type and inspect its properties. Right?

Comment: Right, and I only should drill down when the property's type is created for me. In the parent class I should drill down Child property but no PropertyOne

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you mean by "user-defined" - are you trying to spot the difference between an automatically implemented property and one which has been written by hand? If so, an automatically implemented property will have the `[CompilerGenerated]` attribute on the getter and the setter.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

class Program
{
    public int AutomaticallyImplemented { get; set; }
    public int HandWritten {
        get { return 0; }
        set {}
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var property in typeof(Program).GetProperties())
        {
            bool auto = property.GetGetMethod().IsDefined
                (typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", property.Name, auto);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously you'd normally want to check whether there *is* a getter first :)

Comment: Good to know, but I believe that's not about auto-implemented accessors.

Comment: @Matias: It was the closest I could guess based on the lack of information in the question. It's *completely* unclear what the OP is after.

Comment: Absolutely agreed :) It's just a comment!

Comment: @JonSkeet I just came across this as I am looking for the same thing. I think what he's asking (at least at first glance) is to get all properties that were defined by the developer rather than inherited from Object. The only way I can think of doing is to decorate each property with a custom attr :/

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: Well `Object` doesn't have any properties, so that wouldn't be a problem. With the new reflection API you could use `type.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties`... that would get properties declared in that class rather than inherited, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get those non-inherited members, try [Type.GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx), and pass `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` as an argument like:

```
var properties  = typeof(test).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Comment: And what if inheritance has more than one level? :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to know which one aren't .NET Framework ones.

You can invoke Type.GetProperties and iterate found properties with LINQ in order to know where these were defined in your class, and which ones, in framework level.

As others said, you need PropertyInfo.DeclaringType to know where some property was defined.

If any of your project's object are inheriting from some base class, maybe you can do this:

```
someObject.GetType().GetProperties().Where(propInfo => propInfo.DeclaringType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ProjectBaseType))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like a 'user defined' property. To learn in what type in an inheritance hierarchy a property was declared, have a look at [`PropertyInfo.DeclaringType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to findout whether or not a property is inherited compare the PropertyInfo.DeclaringType to the Type you are testing